# Please help me debug this error about for/in in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning about javascript basic, and i have a problem with for/in and for/of.

```
var courses = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function (callback, initialValue) {
    var sum = initialValue;
    for(var value of this) {
        sum = callback(sum, value);
    }
    return sum;
}

function func(total, number) {
    return total + number;
}

var sum = courses.reduce2(func, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

This program is used to define reduce2 function which caculate sum of values in array. In reduce2, I use for/of and it returns the correct result.

```
for(var value of this) {
    sum = callback(sum, value);
}
```

However, when i use for/in, it return the incorrect result.

```
for(var i in this) {
    sum = callback(sum, this[i]);
}
```

And this is result.

```
 10function (callback, initialValue) {
    var sum = initialValue;
    for(var i in this) {
        sum = callback(sum, this[i]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Please help me, thank you very much!!!

Comment: `for in` iterates indexes, `for of` iterates values.

Comment: `this` in the function refers to the function, is this what you wanted?

Comment: `for..in` is for iterating over object *properties*, `for...of` is for iterating over array *values*.

Comment: `this` in the function I want to refer to the array which use this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) docs

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object

So, in your case when using `for...in` at the end of array values `i` will be `reduce2` so `this[i]` refers to `reduce2` function. You can see the output of the below snippet while using `for...in`.

```js
var courses = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function(callback, initialValue) {
  var sum = initialValue;
  for (var i in this) {
    console.log(`this[${i}]: ${this[i]}`);
    sum = callback(sum, this[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

function func(total, number) {
  return total + number;
}

var sum = courses.reduce2(func, 0);
```

As, `this[i]` is being passed to the callback function it's getting appended to the final output i.e., function declaration itself is getting appended to `10` in this case.

In order to avoid that while using `for...in`, we can make use of [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and get the desired output.

```js
var courses = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function (callback, initialValue) {
    var sum = initialValue;
    for(var i in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
          sum = callback(sum, this[i]);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

function func(total, number) {
    return total + number;
}

var sum = courses.reduce2(func, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

`for..in` not go thru the indexes.  As @nithish mentioned, it will iterate over properties.
Better to use classic `for loop` to iterate the index and get the desired behaviour for the array items.

```js
var courses = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function (callback, initialValue) {
  var sum = initialValue;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    sum = callback(sum, this[i]);
  }
  return sum;
};

function func(total, number) {
  return total + number;
}

var sum = courses.reduce2(func, 0);
console.log(sum);
```